# Leap year convention in python datetime

Tags: python, datetime, leap-year

I'm reading data in which the time variable was encoded with udunits. This means that the time variable is hours since 1-1-1 00:00:00, however, it does not follow standard leap year conventions.

I'm trying to convert the hours since 1-1-1 00:00:00 to a python datetime object but end up with the incorrect answer because datetime does follow leap year convention. For example:

```
t_data = 17584272    # This is time stamp for January 1st, 2007 in the data file
day = datetime.datetime(1,1,1) + datetime.timedelta(hours=t_data)
print(day)
```

Result:

```
>>> 2007-01-03 00:00:00
```

Is there a way to 'turnoff' leap year convention in python datetime?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: There's no way to turn off leap years in `datetime`, but there's a way to correct your time stamp. Can you give a few more examples, particularly ones that are a few years spread out?

Comment: The short answer is no. There do seem to be some udunits interfaces for Python, though, e.g. https://code.google.com/p/cfunits-python/

Comment: `17584272.0/24.0/365.0 == 2007.34`, which implies that without leap days, the date should be a third of the way into 2007 (i.e. April sometime).

Comment: how do you figure that that is 1/1/2007?

Comment: @MarkRansom Here are some more examples: 1/1/1990 = 1.7435256E7, 1/1/1995 = 1.747908E7, 1/1/2000 = 1.7522904E7, 1/1/2013 = 1.763688E7 Thanks!

Comment: @chrisaycock you guys are correct. Actually, it's not clear to me what how udunits handles leap years. All I could find so far was that is does not follow standard leap year conventions. I'll retract the question till I can look at udunits more closely. Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're incorrect in your assessment that leap years aren't being used properly, all of the samples you've listed are consistent. There's just some offset that you need to account for. It's not necessary to know what the offset is, you just start with a known date and hour figure.

```
def udtimestamp(hours):
    return datetime.datetime(1990,1,1) + datetime.timedelta(hours=hours-17435256)

>>> for x in (17584272,1.7435256E7,1.747908E7,1.7522904E7,1.763688E7):
    print udtimestamp(x)

2007-01-01 00:00:00
1990-01-01 00:00:00
1995-01-01 00:00:00
2000-01-01 00:00:00
2013-01-01 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input("Enter Year:"))
if n % 4 == 0:
    print("Leap year", n)
else:
    print("Not Leap Year", n)
```

Comment: While simple and it works *most* of the time, the actual definition of leap year is more complicated than just mod 4.